# Can I use if statement instead of triple nested for loop to make my algorithm faster?

Tags: algorithm

```
for (i = 1 to n)
  for (j = 1 to n)
    for (k = j+1 to n)
      if (A(i, j) = A(i, k)) return false;
for (k = 1 to n)
  for (i = 1 to n)
    for (j = i+1 to n)
      if (A(i, k) = A(j, k)) return false;
```

return true;
The pseudocode here is an algorithm to verify a n x n matrix is Latin square or not, but my assignment requires to design an faster algorithm which is O(n^2) running time.  So, I'm thinking if I simply remove those two third inner loop and change to if statement such like,

```
for (i = 1 to n)
  for (j = 1 to n)
    if (k <= n)
      k = j + 1;
      if (A(i, j) = A(i, k)) return false;
for (k = 1 to n)
  for (i = 1 to n)
    if (j <= n)
      j = i + 1;
      if (A(i, k) = A(j, k)) return false;
```

I have been stuck on this question for 2 hours and still come up nothing. This idea is actually from one of my friends. Just here to verify if I can do that, after removing the third inner loop and add if statement, does this algorithm's running time become faster?  Any response will help, thanks.

Comment: The second version of code is wrong. First version test for n - j values while the second version test for k = j + 1 only

Comment: If X is a finite set, then a function f:X-> X is injective if it is onto. This means that you can check if all elements in a row are different simply by checking that you got in the row all the elements in the alphabet with which the supposed Latin square it filled. Checking whether you got all the values in a row is faster than directly checking that all elements are different.

Comment: Programming is not the Art of Combining Statements Randomly.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Clearly false.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code block will not do the verification correctly:

- *k* never receives an initial value.
- `if (A(i, j) = A(i, k))` comes down to `if (A(i, j) = A(i, j+1))`, which is not enough as a test: this will not detect duplicates when they are not adjacent.

One way to do it with *O(n²)* time complexity, is to use [hash sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)). Many programming languages provide this data structure allowing insertion and membership-test operations to execute with a *O(1)* time complexity (amortised).

Using a set, you can verify in *O(n)* whether a row (or column) has *n* distinct values. To ensure that there are no more than *n* distinct values *overall*, you could also use a set.

So here is the pseudo code for that:

```
if A is not square: 
    return false
allValues = set()
for (i = 1 to n)
    rowValues = set()
    colValues = set()
    for (j = 1 to n)
        rowValues.add( A(i, j) )
        colValues.add( A(j, i) )
        allValues.add( A(i, j) )
    if (colValues.size != n) return false
    if (rowValues.size != n) return false
if (allValues.size != n) return false
return true
```

If the values in the matrix *A* are supposed to be in the range *1..n*, then you can also use arrays instead of sets. Then the pseudo code would like this:

```
if A is not square: 
    return false
for (i = 1 to n)
    rowValues = Array(size = n).fillWith(0)
    colValues = Array(size = n).fillWith(0)
    for (j = 1 to n)
        if (A(i, j) < 1 or A(i, j) > n) return false
        if (rowValues( A(i, j) ) != 0) return false
        rowValues( A(i, j) ) = 1
        if (rowValues( A(j, i) ) != 0) return false
        colValues( A(j, i) ) = 1
return true
```

Comment: If the values are supposed to be in the range 1..n then the sum of each row or column should be n(n+1)/2, so you don't need arrays to find duplicates.

Comment: @PeteKirkham, there are many ways to arrive at that sum. Example: 1+2+3 = 2+2+2.

Answer (score 0):

Use an histogram, i.e. an array of counters.

For every row, clear the counters (N operations), scan the row and increment the counter for every element (N operations); if a counter reaches 2, return "not Latin".

You repeat this for the N rows and N columns.